# Unable to create tags?

Tags: support

I am trying to post a question but it says I don't have a high enough reputation to create tags, so I try posting without tags but they are required.  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have found the answer yourself, but I will answer in case anyone else comes looking.

You must use already existing tags.  This was likely problematic since when you asked this question the site was brand new, so almost any tag would be a new tag.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to ask before any questions had been made.  There weren't any tags =\